# No styling with Devise and Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Every time I install devise with rails it installs just fine and works as expected, the only problem is that there is no styling. I've watched a few tutorials on railscasts and on youtube and it seems that whenever devise is installed there is a default style (blue background, white box containing the sign_up/sign_in form). When I use devise I don't get this styling (in other words: my views are unstyled). What could the problem be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the design you describe in Railscasts is generated [by the nifty-generators](https://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators). Styling is not part of Devise.

To have the same look & feel, install the gem and run:

```
rails g nifty:layout
```